# Fonts for different types of thickness

Tags: flash, apache-flex, actionscript-3, air

This css can set style for all normal Arial, but I have Arial bold in project, how can I apply bold font for them?

```
 @font-face {
    src:url("fonts/ARIAL.TTF");
    fontFamily: Arial;
    advancedAntiAliasing: true;
 }
 global {
    font-family: Arial;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@font-face {
   src:url("fonts/ARIAL.TTF");
   fontFamily: Arial;
   advancedAntiAliasing: true;
}
@font-face {
   src:url("fonts/ARIALBD.TTF");
   fontFamily: Arial;
   fontWeight: bold;
   advancedAntiAliasing: true;
}
@font-face {
   src:url("fonts/ARIALI.TTF");
   fontFamily: Arial;
   fontStyle: italic;
   advancedAntiAliasing: true;
}
@font-face {
   src:url("fonts/ARIALBI.TTF");
   fontFamily: Arial;
   fontWeight: bold;
   fontStyle: italic;
   advancedAntiAliasing: true;
}
     @font-face {
        src:url("fonts/ariblk.TTF");
        fontFamily: ArialBlack;
        advancedAntiAliasing: true;
     }
```

Comment: To add to this, every time you embed fonts, your app gets considerably larger.  Doing it for every style and font weight increases it even more.

Comment: @J_A_X Isn't using the 'url' syntax, the equivalent of loading fonts at runtime as opposed to embedding them?

Comment: @www.Flextras.com, nope.  They're just following CSS conventions, it's still embedding the fonts.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that "Bold" fonts are separate than the non-bold fonts.  So, if you want to bold something using Arial.TFF you'll also have to include Arialdb.tff (or similar).

More information on fonts included with Microsoft Office is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/837463).  The Arial Bold companion to Arial.tff is "Arialbd.ttf" (Look under the Office XP section).

Comment: Thank you for answer. How can I set globally that bold font?

Comment: @Tuco What do you mean by set globally?  You mean you want everything to be bold?  If so, then just use the bold font instead of the non-bold font.  Since you posted a code snippet as an answer; does that contain your solution?